# Excel 2007 VBA code to aggregate data based on conditions and calculate a weighted average

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am importing data from a trading system that has buy and sell orders for multiple securities(stocks).  I need to aggregate the same security buy orders and the same security sell orders, creating a total number of shares bought and sold, and then calculating a weighted average price for the sale and buy.  Eliminating the multiple lines and keeping the aggregate positions.

Columns look like this:

ID /Trade Date/Settlement Date/Route ID/Ticker/Name/Country/Currency/Action/Type/ Size/Price/Broker/CUSIP/ISIN/SEDOL/Commission/FX

So I need to sum the Size column based on the Action and Ticker (ie MSFT Buy) and then get a weighted average of those (all of the MSFT "Buy" executions for example).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming column A = `ID`the simplest way to do it is with a sumproduct formula -

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(F:F="MSFT"),--(J:J="BUY"),M:M,L:L)/SUMIF(F:F,"=MSFT",L:L)`

This is assuming a weighted average is `(Price*Size)/(Sum of all Sizes)`

This isn't a VBA solution, but it's simple and it works.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, it Sums all shares in the sheet.  I need the weighted average price of the aggregate buys and aggregate sells of each security, based on that security only, not the whole sheet.

Comment: @EricR So use a sumif instead of a sum. See edited answer. If this isn't what you need, please express what you need in terms of column letter because I can't follow.